# how to show that the only rational solutions of the equation $x^4+y^4=1$ are $(0,土1), (土1,0)$?

Tags: number-theory

how to show that the only rational solutions of the equation $x^4+y^4=1$ are $(0,土1), (土1,0)$ ?

the hint seems like descent argument, but I can't find how to formulate the argument... Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: It can be derived from here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Non-solvability_of_r2_.2B_s4_.3D_t4

Comment: For those curious, the equation in question defines a [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) called [squircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle).

Answer (score 1):

The proof by descent is given for the Fermat equation $x^4+y^4=z^4$ in books on number theory. A very good reference are the notes of Keith Conrad on [Proofs by descent](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/descent.pdf), section $3$, Corollary $3.3$:

**Corollary 3.3.** Any rational solution to $x^4 + y^4 = z^2$ has $x$ or $y$ equal to $0$.

For $z^2=1$ it follows $(x,y)=(0,\pm 1),(\pm 1,0)$.